# $\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$ is an index two subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, combinatorial-group-theory, free-product

I want to prove $\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$ is an index two subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$. Can I use covering map to prove this? Any ideas and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can use coverings. Your group is the fundamental group of the graph with a single vertex and two loop edges. Take your favourite map to the cyclic group of order two; the corresponding cover is a graph with two vertices and four edges, and with the required fundamental group. (The precise graph you obtain relies on the map you use, but the number of vertices and edges are fixed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use coverings. In fact, you can use coverings to prove that *every* subgroup of index two is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z\ast Z\ast Z}$.

To use coverings, note that your group is the fundamental group of the graph with a single vertex and two loop edges.

A two-sheeted cover of this graph is a connected graph with two vertices, each with degree four. Up to isomorphism there are 2 such graphs (two edges between the two vertices, or four). In each case, the graph has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z\ast Z\ast Z}$, as required.

Answer (score 3):

Directly:
Define $\color{red}{\Bbb Z}*\color{green}{\Bbb Z}*\color{blue}{\Bbb Z}\to \color{red}{\Bbb Z}*\color{green}{\Bbb Z} $ by $\color{red}1\mapsto \color{red}2$, $\color{green}1\mapsto \color{green}2$, $\color{blue}1\mapsto \color{red}1\cdot\color{green}1$.

If you use $a$, $b$, and  $c$ as the standard generators of $\mathbb{Z\ast Z\ast Z}$, and $x$ and $y$ for $\mathbb{Z\ast Z}$, then this map is given by

\begin{align}
a &\mapsto x^2 \\
b &\mapsto y^2 \\
c &\mapsto xy
\end{align}

Comment: I appreciate the bold and innovative use of color, but it would be a heck of a lot clearer if you wrote it with $\langle a, b, c\rangle \rightarrow \langle x, y\rangle$.

Comment: I edited it to add the alternative description. I figured a 300k+ rep user wouldn't mind. Feel free to delete the edit if you don't like it, HvonE.

Comment: I'll also add that for me this is the clearest description of the covering map possible.